# What encryption algorithm is used by LibreOffice Writer to password protect .docx files?

Tags: password, encryption, libreoffice

I know LibreOffice uses AES 256 encryption when password protecting files in ODF format. But what about when saving as a .docx file? If I create a document in Writer and save as .docx with password protection, what encryption algorithm is used?